# Check a substring is contained in a string and has at least the first 4 characters

Tags: bash, awk

The string of example is:

```
abcdefghijklmno
```

If I give in input:

```
abc                 FALSE    #at least 4 characters.
abcd                TRUE
cdefg               FALSE    #because the match must start from the first character.
abcde               TRUE
abcdeghi            FALSE    #because the characters must be contained consecutively.
abcdefgh            TRUE
abcdefghi           TRUE
abcdefghijklmno     TRUE
abcdefghijklmnop    FALSE    #because it exceeds the example string.
```

i have tried:

```
set -- abc
i=1
[[ abcdefghijklmno == ${!i}* ]]
echo $?
```

but `echo "$?"` returns `0` also with 3, 2, 1 or 0 characters.

This other code is obviously wrong but it is to communicate what I would like to do:

```
set -- abc
i=1
[[ abcdefghijklmno == ${!i}{4}* ]]
echo $?
```

EDIT:

The solution that suits me is the following:

```
set -- abc
i=1
[[ abcdefghijklmno == ${!i}* && $(expr length "${!i}") -ge 4 ]]
echo $?
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code?

Comment: Why is `cdefg` false?

Comment: Because the match must start from the first character.

Comment: Sorry, next time I think better about the post to be published instead of editing continuously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may us this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v s='abcdefghijklmno' '{
print $0, (length($1) > 3 && index(s, $1) == 1 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")}' file | column -t

abc               FALSE
abcd              TRUE
cdefg             FALSE
abcde             TRUE
abcdeghi          FALSE
abcdefgh          TRUE
abcdefghi         TRUE
abcdefghijklmno   TRUE
abcdefghijklmnop  FALSE
```

**Explained:**

- `column` command has been used for tabular output only.
- `length($1) > 3 && index(s, $1) == 1`: Check condition that length of first field is greater than `3` and `$1` is found from first position in the given string `s`.

*Alternatively*, we can also use a regex to check presence of `$1` from start:

```
awk -v s='abcdefghijklmno' '{
   print $0, (length($1) > 3 && s ~ "^" $1 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")
}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`index`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index) function of Perl seems adapted: given two strings, it returns the index at which the second one occurs in the first one, or -1 if it does not occur. What you want to do is thus to check if the second string appears in the first one, at the index 0. Then, you can use the [`length`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length) function to make sure that the second string is more than 4 characters long

For instance,

```
length("abc") >= 4 && index("abcdefghijklmno", "abc") == 0                # true
length("cdefg") >= 4 && index("abcdefghijklmno", "cdefg") == 0            # false
length("abcdefghijklmno") >= 4 && index("abcdefghijklmno", "abcdefghijklmno") == 0    # true
```

To use it in a one-liner, one way is to provide both strings on the command line. For instance:

```
perl -e 'print length($ARGV[1]) >= 4 && index($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]) == 0 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"' abcdefghijklmno abc
```

---

Alternatively, you can sacrifice readability for conciseness by using a regular expression:

```
perl -e 'print $ARGV[0] =~ /^\Q$ARGV[1]\E(?<=.{4})/ ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"' abcdefghijklmno abcde
```

Where the regex checks if the first string starts with the second one (`/^\Q$ARGV[1]\E`), and that the second one is 4 characters long or more (`(?<=.{4})`; see [`perlre#lookaround-assertions`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions)).